Excel VBA set Color of cells to the color of another cell automatically
Hey so I'm currently creating a dynamic calendar for the project schedule in our company. It works quite fine that I enter a start and end date and it marks the right cells via conditional formatting. The problem is we have a lot of projects and we want to seperate them by colors. So I of course could create a different formatting rule for every project.
But since it has to be user friendly for my coworkers I would like them to be able to choose the project color at the beginning and then it will apply to these rows in the calendar aswell.
I read that its possible to change the cell color based on another cells color via VBA. But I couldnt figure out how to use it for my problem. Also I dont know much about vba so it would be amazing if you could explain me the solution codes.
Thanks in advance :)
Here a picture for easier understanding:

I also tried to only make black borders and manually apply the fill color since that would be no problem aswell. But I cant fill a cell that has conditional formatting on it so that doesnt work.

As you note - if a cell has a fill from CF you can't manually overide that by setting a different fill.  It's not very clear from your screenshot where the "project" is, or what existing CF rules you might have which might be in conflict with the "color by project" requirement.

It's certainly possible, but you'll need to understand a bit about VBA to do this. We are not a code writing service, you have to make your own.
For instance, you could retrieve the color used in cell A1 of the first worksheet by including:
Dim clr as Variant
clr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Interior.Color

If you then want to set the color used for the first condition in the conditional format in range B2:E5 on the first worksheet to that same color, you would include:
Worksheets(1).Range("B2:E5").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = clr

But those are just the building blocks; you still have to make a subroutine around them, and decide by what event you want to trigger that subroutine.
